# Properties of the Liouville measure

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure, classical-mechanics

Could someone point me to references where general properties of the Liouville measure, $\mu_L$, would be explicitly discussed?

**Questions:**

1. Can $\mu_L$, as usually defined, always be viewed as a measure in the standard sense of measure theory?
2. If so, what is the underlying $\sigma$-algebra? And does it contain all singletons? Is $\mu_L$ always a $\sigma$-finite measure?
3. Does $\mu_L$ always enjoy some nice continuity properties? Is it e.g. always continuous from above/from below?
4. Is it guaranteed that $\mu_L$ has no point masses?
5. Is $\mu_L$ a probability measure on any energy surface?

**Thoughts:** I've seen geometric definitions of Liouville measure (e.g. [Two different definitions of a Liouville measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356069/two-different-definitions-of-a-liouville-measure)). I don't know whether it's obvious that they settle some/all of the above questions.