Definition of Liouville measure
I want to apply a theorem that describes the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on a Riemannian manifold:

This theorem assumes that the geodesic flow of $M$ is ergodic with respect to the Liouville measure.
What is exactly the definition of the Liouville measure ?: Is it defined on $M$ or $TM$ ?.
In another reference, I saw that this measure is expressed as
$$
\frac{{\rm d}x \wedge {\rm d}\xi}{{\rm d}\left\vert\,\xi\,\right\vert}
$$

Could someone please explain this definition ?. I could not find it in any textbook.




Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356069/two-different-definitions-of-a-liouville-measure?rq=1

The measure is defined on the unit tangent bundle. You can find it's definition in many differential geometry textbooks. See also this MO post.
